# Abrir documento, editar y al cerrar llamar a función callback

Tags: c#, angularjs, navegador-web

Buenos tardes, tengo una duda de si esto se puede hacer.

Tengo una aplicación Web para la gestión de documentos.
Lo que quiero saber es si, al pulsar el botón "Editar Word" por ejemplo, me abra el programa en el equipo y al guardar, que llame a una función callback con el fichero.

Había pensado crear un fichero temporal en el servidor con c# y ejecutar el programa, pero el problema es que lo abre en el servidor, no en cliente.

Sé que suena raro, pero igual conocéis alguna forma de hacer una especie de "puente" entre el navegador y el equipo o si programando alguna extensión se podría realizar. No tengo problema con ningún lenguaje de programación frontend o backend.

Espero que entendáis lo que necesito. Gracias.
Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera medalla. También es interesante leer [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Si entiendo bien tu pregunta,dudo que pueda hacerse sin que en el equipo en el que se edita el Word se instale algún tipo de aplicación que pueda informar al servidor que el archivo se ha guardado.

Comment: Sí hermano, hay algo parecido, requiere buena mano del desarrollador y del sysadmin del server porque hay mucha configuración para que trabaje adecuadamente, échale un ojo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17696309/3613462

Comment: Por lo que veo, habría que usar Sharepoint. Hay alguna manera de integrarlo fácilmente en mi aplicación? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El navegador no tiene acceso al sistema de ficheros donde se está ejecutando en prácticamente ningún caso, y nunca de manera automática. Tampoco puedes lanzar una aplicación de escritorio desde el mismo, ni saber cuándo ésta se cierra, por temas de seguridad.

Posibilidades:

- El usuario se baja el fichero, lo modifica y luego lo vuelve a subir.
- El contenido del fichero es mostrado en un editor online, como [éste](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/)